# read JSON data from PHP with jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, json

I send an array from PHP with `json_encode`, and I trying to get with AJAX and jQuery.
Every thing is ok.

JSON structure is :

```
names{"p1":"John","p5":"Smith"}
```

jQuery code is :

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "return.php",
dataType: "json",
data: "id=56",
success: function(data) {
        $(data.names).each(function(key, txt) {
            alert(txt);
        });
    }
}
```

this code don't return any thing! I think browser don't enter in `each`

what should I do ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead this:

```
$(data.names).each(function(key, txt) {
    alert(txt);
});
```

use this:

```
$.each(data.names, function(key, txt) {
    alert(txt);
});
```

and your json seems to be incorrect as you mentioned: `names{"p1":"John","p5":"Smith"}`

this should be like this:

```
{
    "names": {
        "p1": "John",
        "p5": "Smith"
    }
}
```

you can check your json here: http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you use jQuery's $.getJSON(); http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/
But to answer your question directly; you didn't close your ajax() function.

```
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "return.php",
dataType: "json",
data: "id=56",
success: function(data) {
        $(data.names).each(function(key, txt) {
            alert(txt);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code you could just use **parseJSON**().

```
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "return.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "id=56",
    success: function(data) {
        var d = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
        // ... do stuff
    }
    });
```